# D3 Hexbin Hexagon Grid, why is row vs column offset unpredictable?

Tags: d3.js, game-development, preact, hexagonal-tiles

I'm using D3 to show a grid of hexagons. You can zoom in and out, and it changes the tile size. Sometimes the rows shift from normal, and I don't know how to predict or control it.

I would like the rows and columns to always be predictable in relationship to each other. Otherwise I can't correctly find the adjacent cells.

It's hard to explain so I will provide images. The code for creating the grid is here:

https://github.com/snellcode/insulam/blob/main/src/services/map.ts

[image: good state]

[image: bad state]

I have tried changing the tile size, the size of the map, etc... It also seems like it could be different based on machine or browser. So far I am not able to find the pattern to make it consistent.

I wondered if there is some math I can apply. I imagine somehow shifting every other row to correct for it. I was not able to get this to work either.

Somehow I think there must be some math being done that determines the row vs column alignment. I just need a way to make this predictable.

demo site: https://insulam.got.solar/

Comment: https://github.com/snellcode/insulam/blob/2181c4c165149c0d9d502fb805d0fbd370144ec3/src/services/map.ts#L369C1-L392C5

I would put a breakpoint in that part of your code and check. That's where the colors are being assigned and I think there probably is an error there.

Comment: In one of the the example images you can see one has every other row shifted over by one. The other example does not shift by one. I cannot predict when it will be in one state or the other is the issue. So nothing I do with the colors will change that underlying issue which I need to solve.

Comment: Try truncating or flooring all of the coordinates before plotting the hex grids and see if that at least makes it consistent

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found that if the first row being plotted is an even row, then I have the error. So I think I can use that to make the plotting predictable.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by detecting if the first plotted row is an even or odd number. This makes it reliable as I can correct for it. I still would like to know if one of these variants is more correct than the other. For example, if I am plotting a map I want to make sure locations would show up in the correct relationship to each other.